# Filtering list by multiple values

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a list of object and filter to filter them..

The list is list of object which i will check the values when filter is used

the filter consists of:
- isOpen - isClosed - isSubmitted - isNotSubmitted

and they could select all of them at once, 3 out of 4, 2 out of 4 or even 1

i tried this:

```
List<Poll> closedPolls = <Poll>[];
List<Poll> openPolls = <Poll>[];
List<Poll> submittedPolls = <Poll>[];
List<Poll> notSubmittedPolls = <Poll>[];

if (isOpen) {
    for (var p in openPolls){
      pollsList.add(p);
    }
  }
  if (isClosed) {
    for (var p in closedPolls){
      pollsList.add(p);
    }
  }
  if (isParticipated){
    for (var p in submittedPolls){
      pollsList.add(p);
    }
  }
  if (isNotParticipated){
    for (var p in notSubmittedPolls){
      pollsList.add(p);
    }
  }
```

but this works for only one condition not multiple .. how can i solve this?

Comment: what do you mean by `"multiple condition"`?

Comment: @pskink i mean that the poll could be have to conditions like is open and submitted and so on ..

Comment: If your goal is to merge your different `List<Poll>`s into a single `pollsList` variable based on `isOpen`, `isClosed`, etc., then your code looks fine.  However, it probably doesn't really make sense for `isOpen` and `isClosed` to both be true (nor for `isParticipated` and `isNotParticipated`).  If those conditions are actually independent and `pollsList` isn't being populated as you expect, then either the conditions or the `List<Poll>` variables don't have the values you think they do.

Comment: @jamesdlin but my code doesn't work for example if i selected isopen and issubmitted .. i will get a list of all of the opend polls and submitted .. when i should i get all of the polls which are submitted and opened

Comment: you have couple of `i..f`s, not `if...else..` so it will just work fine (multiple `if` statements will run your `for` loops)

Comment: and why at all you have 4 input lists? why not one single list?

Comment: @mrs.tat My point is that if it "doesn't work", then you need to examine your assumptions, because the code you've presented is fine.  Maybe `isOpen` and `isParticipated` aren't being set correctly, or maybe their corresponding `List<Poll>`s aren't being populated properly.

Comment: @pskink can i make the filter in the same single list?

Comment: @jamesdlin maybe isParticipated and isNotParticipated really doesnt make sense .. but isOpen and isParticipated are actually a combination

Comment: see [Iterable.where](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/Iterable/where.html) method - this is how you should "filter" your data

Comment: @pskink can you give me an example please

Comment: It's really unclear what your intent is here.  Your question talks about filtering, but the code you've posted does the *opposite* of filtering: you're merging a bunch of disparate lists together.

Comment: @jamesdlin thats why i posted the question .. i want a filter

Comment: see [Library Tour  - collections](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/libraries/library-tour#collections)

Comment: @pskink when i tried where i got this error type 'WhereIterable<Poll>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Poll>'

Comment: because it is `Iterable` - read its docs [here](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/Iterable-class.html)